# Oracle Forms Messages are not Shown Except Status Line

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to show custom messages in my form. There are two buttons in different datablocks. When I write 
        "MESSAGE ('Button 1!');"
in WHEN-BUTTON-PRESS trigger of Button 1, it shows message. 
But when I write
        "MESSAGE ('Button 2!');"
in WHEN-BUTTON-PRESS trigger of Button 2, it doesn't show message (it shows message just on status line). 
And if I write my message two time as 
        "MESSAGE ('Button 2!'); MESSAGE ('Button 2!');"
it shows messages. Why? How I can I do?

Comment: Are there any other codes than `MESSAGE ('Button 1!');` within WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger of the button 1 ..?

Answer (score 1):

Message shows a message on the status bar.
If you show 2 messages after each other you can miss the first one, so forms popups the first message to make sure you have seen it. The second message will show back on the status bar.
If you want to want to popup the message you should create an alert and show the alert instead of the message.

If you just use debug messages and want the message to be shown immediately you should put a `pause` behind the message.

```
message("Button 1!");
pause;
```